# Unexpected results depending the position in <head> for jquery-mobile and jquery libraries

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have been working with this problem for days, looking for a solution but I am not able to do alone; I would appreciate some help. It seems a problem of compatibility between libraries.

I have preparing a login form wich is in a section of the page. Other sections are in the page for Home, Who we are and contact aspects. The code for the form is next one:

```
<form name="user_login_form" id="user_login_form_id" action="functions/sessionlogin.php" method="POST">
    <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><p><label for="user_login">User:</label></p></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><input type="text" placeholder="type here user email" name="user_login" id="index_user_login_id" data-clear-btn="true" data-mini="true" maxlength="20" size="20" width="20" /></div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><p><label for="user_login_password">Password:</label></p></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><input type="password" placeholder="type here user password" name="user_login_password" id="index_user_login_password_id" data-clear-btn="true" data-mini="true" maxlength="20" size="20" /></div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><input id="user_login_btn_id" type="submit" value="Login" /></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><input id="reset_form_btn_id" type="reset" value="Cancel" /></div>
    </fieldset>                 
</form>
```

When Login button pressed, it moves to an authentication function and moves to an internal page if validation succeed, or comes back if validated failed. Functions work fine. The problem I have comes up more due to the stylish of the page.

The fact is that, when typing the info in the  of my page like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script_index.js"></script>
<style>
   .ui-grid-a .ui-block-a { width: 50%; }
   .ui-grid-a .ui-block-b { width: 50%; }
</style>
```

The result is that the page does its work, validate and moves to the internal page BUT the style is not fine. Some features are lost. Sections are not being activated in the page, div inside accordion are displayed with a border line...

On the other hand, changing the position of:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

with code resulting as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script_index.js"></script>
<style>
   .ui-grid-a .ui-block-a { width: 50%; }
   .ui-grid-a .ui-block-b { width: 50%; }
</style>
```

The result is that the style is the one I expect and wish. Elements are shown correctly without unexpected behaviour BUT the call to the php function is not executed. The URL changes to the php function but it stops there.

Thank you in advance for your help.

David

Comment: Try placing all `<link>` and `<style>` elements before the `<script>` elements. There are known bugs in browsers concerning the order of these elements.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. I have tried like that, but it does not work. Very strange.